# What is the difference between "views" path and the path used in express.static?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have never used Express for more than a static HTML server serving JavaScript and HTML to WebSocket app. I am now very confused with some example code which I'm trying to get to work.

After I updated the example for latest Express version, the initialization code looks like this:

```
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
// One path...
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(methodOverride());

var path = require ('path');
// Another path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

I am familiar with the `express.static`. That's the path where static HTML, images, scripts and other files are hosted. But the other path bothers me, I do not understand those two lines:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug'); // Maybe some HTML template parser???
```

The problem is, that this actually causes errors:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "`... project path .../views`"

I am not here just to fix the error though. I'm far more interested in knowing what does the code I have mean. Can anyone explain to me, what am I doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`views` are not static. When you use the `response.render` method, `express` will look up the provided template name string to find a template which it then parses and emits.

If you have `/views/index.pug` that contains something like:

```
html
  body
    h1= message
```

You can create a route:

```
app.get('/' (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {message: "hello"});
});
```

If you want to access something in your static directory, you can use that route directly as well.

[More information about `express` template engine usage is here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I'm starting to get it. But for some reason, going to `localhost:3000` uses the `public/index.html` statically, but all other requests seem to use `pug` files as you say they would. My code for `app.get('/'` is same as yours, just one line with `res.render`... It doesn't bug me very much, but I don't understand it at all...

Comment: Here's my full code for clarity, but I think it's just as you anticipated: https://gist.github.com/Darker/c016ff3d43100e2aa43addc2416381e4 Code below line 50 is already after the initialization.

Comment: Middlewares are used in the order written, so since `.static` is used before `.get('/'`, `public/index.html` is served first before the other view is rendered